# How can I use Windows-Key shortcuts inside a Windows RDP running on Mac OS?

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

I've recently swtiched from a Windows work PC to a Mac Book Pro. Most of my development work is done over an RDP connection to a Windows 2012 server.

When doing development work, I use IDE's and other tools that have custom keyboard shortcuts involving the Windows key. For instance, `[win]+[backtick]` is set to open a console. As long as I was connected to the RDP session in full-screen mode, the Windows key combinations were passed through to the RDP session and interperted correctly.

Howver, on my Mac Book Pro, I cannot trigger any of my custom Windows key shortcuts. What is weird, is that all of the built in Windows key shortcuts still work. For example. `[win]+[e]` opens Windows Explorer, and `[win]+[d]` still minimzes all windows to show the desktop. Also, pressing the Windows button by itself bring up the start menu, as normal. But none of the user assigned key combinations involving the Windows key work is any application (I've tried three apps). Custom key bindings involving the ctrl, alt, and shift keys work as expected.

#### Config

I'm running:

- Mac Book Pro 2017
- MacOS Mojave 10.14
- Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 10.1

I have the "Use Mac shortcuts for cut, copy, and paste" option unchcked from within Remote Desktop Client preferences.

Based on a different question and answer, it looks like there are some configuration files in Applications --> Microsoft Remote Desktop --> Package Contents --> Contents --> Resources --> Keyboard. However, I'm not sure what I would add to map [Win]+[something].

Comment: That's because remote desktop for macOS "cheats" and only captures a fixed set of hotkey combinations, and leaves the rest to the OS. It's likely to be a limitation imposed by macOS. There should be a way to extend the list of the captured hotkeys, one-by-one though.

Comment: The Windows key is owned by Microsoft. It's not intended to be used by third-party applications, or even first-party applications. It's exclusively reserved for use by the OS.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't think that is accurate. Many Windows apps allow use of the win button as a modifier key. The .net and other Microsoft libraries have constants on KEY EVENT to detect it, and treat it the same as CTRL, or ALT. Do you have a source you could link?

Comment: [Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key are reserved for use by the operating system.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [repo](https://github.com/satween/MacOsLinuxRDPBindings)

Probably you can adjust this configuration file for your goals